# How do you replace a whole row of a data.table with NA?

Tags: r, data.table

This seems like something that should be easy but I can't figure it out.

```
>d=data.table(x=1:5,y=11:15,z=letters[1:5])
>d
   x  y z
1: 1 11 a
2: 2 12 b
3: 3 13 c
4: 4 14 d
5: 5 15 e
```

Now, I have decided that row 3 is bad data. I want all of those set to NA.

```
d[3,]<-NA
```

> Warning message:
>       In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 3, , value = NA) :
>         Coerced 'logical' RHS to 'character' to match the column's type. Either change the target column to 'logical' first (by creating a new
>   'logical' vector length 5 (nrows of entire table) and assign that;
>   i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'character' (e.g. 1L,
>   NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for
>   speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the
>   table and stick to it, please.

Yet, it seems to work.

```
> d
    x  y  z
1:  1 11  a
2:  2 12  b
3: NA NA NA
4:  4 14  d
5:  5 15  e
```

If I convert to data.frame, it also works but without the warning. But then I need to convert back which seems awkward. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want to set the complete row to `NA`, why not just remove it?

Answer (score 9):

To set by reference.

```
DT[rownum, (names(DT)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {  .x <- x[1]; is.na(.x) <- 1L; .x})]
```

Or perhaps

```
DT[rownum, (names(DT)) := lapply(.SD[1,], function(x) { is.na(x) <- 1L; x})]
```

This will ensure that the correct NA type is created (factor and dates as well)

The second case only indexes once, this may be slightly faster if there are lots of columns in DT or rownum creates a large subgroup of rows.

You could also do (a variant on Roland's solution, but with no copying.

```
DT[rownum, (names(DT)) := .SD[NA]]
```

Comment: +1. I guess I need to better understand when `data.table` makes copies and so on. I like your last option best.

Comment: Actually, `DT[rownum, (names(DT)) := .SD[NA]]` is neat!  Maybe that is better than `set()`, thinking about it.

Answer (score 7):

Use the explicit `NA` types:

```
d[3,] <- list(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_character_)
```

Another possibility:

```
d[3,] <- d[3,lapply(.SD,function(x) x[NA])]
```

Comment: These will copy the entire data.table by using [<-

Answer (score 3):

What about using `?set`?

```
> d=data.table(x=1:5,y=11:15,z=letters[1:5])
> set(d, 3L, 1:3, NA_character_)
> d
    x  y  z
1:  1 11  a
2:  2 12  b
3: NA NA NA
4:  4 14  d
5:  5 15  e
> str(d)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 NA 4 5
 $ y: int  11 12 NA 14 15
 $ z: chr  "a" "b" NA "d" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Or, simply:

```
> d=data.table(x=1:5,y=11:15,z=letters[1:5])
> d[3] <- NA_character_
> str(d)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 NA 4 5
 $ y: int  11 12 NA 14 15
 $ z: chr  "a" "b" NA "d" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

---

[ From Matthew ] Yes either `set()` is the way to go, or @mnel's answer is very neat :

```
DT[rownum, names(DT) := .SD[NA]]
```

On the presence or not of the coerce warning in the `set` approach, here's the internal code (modified here to convey the salient points). I seem to have had loss of precision (from `double` to `integer`) in mind when writing that, as well as inefficiency of coercing the RHS.

```
if( (isReal(RHS) && (TYPEOF(targetcol)==INTSXP || isLogical(targetcol))) ||
    (TYPEOF(RHS)==INTSXP && isLogical(targetcol)) ||
    (isString(targetcol))) {
    if (isReal(RHS)) s3="; may have truncated precision"; else s3="";
    warning("Coerced '%s' RHS to '%s' to match the column's type%s. ... <s3> ...
}
```

The full source of assign.c can be inpected here :
 https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/src/assign.c?view=markup&root=datatable

There is a very similar feature request to improve this :

[FR#2551 Singleton := RHS no coerce warning if no precision lost](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2551&group_id=240&atid=978)

Have added a link there back to this question.

In general where `data.table` is over cautious in warning you about potential problems or inefficiencies,  in a case like this where you want to set a set of column of different types, wrapping with `suppressWarnings()` is another way.

Comment: I guess this answer just masks the warning... by manually doing what the warning seems to be describing that *it* is automatically doing.

Comment: I should have been a little more specific. I want to be able to do this with any general data.table. So to do this, I'd have to query the class of each column.

Comment: Don't use `[<-` I'm pretty sure this copies the whole object (even for data.tables), that is why `:=` and `set` were implemented.

Comment: Great use of `set` (although I'm unclear why it works without matching the NA types. (as is required with `:=`, and sometimes with `set`)

Comment: Yes, `set` is the way to go. I was scrolling down hoping someone would say `set` :) As @mnel says `[<-` will copy (the whole `DT`). On the warning I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing now. Ok, I guess but still a little awkward.

```
na_datatable_row<-function(dtrow){
  #take a row of data.table and return a row of the same table but 
  #with all values set tp NA
  #DT[rownum,]<-NA works but throws an annoying warning 
  #so instead, do DT[rownum,]<-na_datatable_row(DT[anyrow,]) 
  #this preserves the right types
  row=data.frame(dtrow)
  row[1,]<-NA
  return(data.table(row))
}
```